# Identify differential equation type and solve it numerically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to simulate transitional processes in RF filters. Mathematical model of the circuit is a system of $N$ equations. Each looks like this: $$a\frac{d^2i_j(t)}{dt^2}=bi_j+c\frac{di_j(t)}{dt}+d\frac{d^2i_{j-1}(t)}{dt^2}+e\frac{d^2i_{j+1}(t)}{dt^2}$$ , where $j$ is the index of the equation in the system.
It doesn't look like any equation system I've seen because each equation depends on the solutions of it's neighbors. What kind of equation are those? Can I split them into ODEs, and, if not, how can I solve this system?

### Edit

Forgot to add that one of the equations would have an additional summand $g\sin{(\omega t)}$ corresponding to the driving force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you have a coupled system of the form
$$
A\ddot x=B\dot x+Cx
$$
where $A,B,C$ are tridiagonal resp. diagonal matrices. For a numerical solution you need a first order system. Introduce $y=\dot x$ then this system is
\begin{align}
\dot x&=y\\
\dot y&=A^{-1}(By+Cx)
\end{align}

Comment: This is the first thing I've tried to do. But then I would get $\dot y_{i} = y + \dot y_{i+1} + \dot y_{i-1}$. And I cannot solve it because $\dot y_{i+1}$ and $\dot y_{i-1}$ in the right part of equation are unknown.

Comment: No, they are to be transferred to the left side that contains all second derivatives as per the first equation. Then the tridiagonal matrix $A$ has to be inverted, so you have to make sure the inverse exist.

Comment: I think I get it now. Thanks! Math is awesome!

Comment: Sorry, don't have enough rating to upvote.